# CoffeeScript: ImapConnection is not defined in node-imap

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am trying to run example Coffee Scripts from: [CoffeScript and node-imap](https://gist.github.com/bergie/1226809)

Sending messages works fine, but when I attempt to read a message, I got this kind of error:

```
TypeError: imap.ImapConnection is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rmatuszak/Dokumenty/NodeJS/mail/coffee2/read.coffee:15:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rmatuszak/Dokumenty/NodeJS/mail/coffee2/read.coffee:7:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.exports.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:134:23)
  at compileScript (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:224:29)
  at compilePath (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:174:14)
  at Object.exports.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:98:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee:7:41)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
  at startup (node.js:139:18)
  at node.js:968:3
```

On the homepage of this gist someone mentioned about this issue, but didn't get answer. Did anyone had issue like that?

Comment: Please post your solution to the original question and ask a new question regarding the timeout problem

Answer (score 0):

I got it ;) according to [this link](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap), I realized, that I have to create a new imap object using `server = new imap` as it was declared in the beggining of script.