# CoffeeScript: TimeOut Error while authenticating with server using node-imap

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

according to my previous problem, which is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351949/coffeescript-imapconnection-is-not-defined-in-node-imap/38366539#38366539), I got this error while using `read.coffee`

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Timed out while authenticating with server
  at [object Object]._onTimeout (/home/rmatuszak/Dokumenty/NodeJS/mail/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:138:17)
  at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

I read somwhere, that TimeOut for authenticating with server is default 5s, but I don't how it is related in connectiong with Google IMAP and how should I change it to get it working.

Comment: Could you please include your `read.coffee` file?

Comment: Here is my `read.coffee` file [read.coffee](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3zrwxGe2A5EWGsyNnRKb1UwSlE) I Have figured out, whre to change authentication time, in node-imap package it can be changed in `Connection.js` file `(node_modules/imap/lib)`. I have changed it to 15s, script works, but it doesn't save any file or eve log me.

Answer (score 0):

You are following a [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/bergie/1226809) which is 5 years old, and are fixing it by subbing in some lines from the up-to-date documentation `https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap`.

You should find a newer tutorial or just follow the official documentation.

For example, you need to define a

```
imap.once('ready', function() { ... })
```

callback. The reason that the connection was timing out isn't that the server was taking too long to get back, but that you don't respond to it once it's `ready` as you don't have the above `imap.once('ready', callback)` callback defined.

Comment: Following your advise, I eliminated the timeout problem. Another issue: script doesn't do antyhing know. I just start, it works for a second and nothing in the command line shows.